# How can a URL tab locator be programmed in Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: list, firefox, google-chrome, search, tabs

I want to create an extension that when a link is hovered over or right clicked, can search for all the tabs opened to the website, bring up a list of them and allow you to select one of them to jump to, or create a new tab for that website if none exists.

Is it possible in Firefox or Chrome with Javascript? The List All Tabs button in goes part of the way, but only shows the page titles, rather than include the URL with it.